# Automating subtracting two layers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geology

Using QGIS, I would like to calculate the difference in depth between several geological horizons. I have one horizon that covers a large area (horizon1) and several smaller horizons (horizon2, horizon3, ...) within that area. All of these horizons have X,Y,Z values.

So basically I'd like to make new horizons which show the difference between the Z-values between horizon1 and the other smaller horizons. I have been able to do this in other (seismic) software manually, but I have so many horizons that I would like to be able to automate this. I can convert these horizons into shapefiles or rasters if necessary. I also have bounding polygons for the smaller horizons.

Edit: An example in this figure: the green dots (200x200 spacing) show horizon1, the dark red dots show horizon2 (50x50 spacing). After interpolating and using the raster calculator (horizon1-horizon2) I get this funny looking raster in black and white on the figure. Not sure why this isn't working. The black lines show bounding polygons of the smaller horizons (horizon2, horizon2, etc).
[image: point files]

[image: raster images]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to GIS Stack Exchange. Since most of us are not geologists, your question would probably be more easily answered if you explained what a horizon is, or (better) if you added illustrations to your question.

Comment: For automating a multi-step process, try the graphical modeler. https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/processing/modeler.html

Comment: Thank you. I have added a figure so it's hopefully a bit more clear. 
Once I get the raster calculator to work I will try the graphical modeler. Thank you for pointing me towards this.

Answer (score 3):

Import your XYZ data as points layer first. If they import all as one layer, you'll probably want to **split vector layer** on the `horizon` attribute.

From this point, it's hard to say without seeing the distribution of points, but I imagine you'll want to **interpolate** into raster layers, `horizon_a`, and so forth. The method you use to interpolate is also going to depend a lot on what your points look like. For example, in a project I worked on calculating sediment volume in a river impoundment using sediment core data, I ended up using **TIN interpolation** due to the sparseness of points.

From there, it's as simple as running the **raster calculator**, with an expression like `horizon_a@1 - horizon_b@1`, the output being a raster of the difference between them.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have added a figure to the question to clarify. After interpolation and subtracting both rasters I get the black & white raster shown in the image, so not what I was looking for. I don't even understand how it got to this raster. Swapping the order in subtracting gives the same result.

Comment: Can you add screenshots of the two interpolated rasters? The calculator is likely restricting your results to the maximum extent an input.

Comment: I have added an image with the rasters. Different colourbars to show the difference between the 2.

Comment: How strange! What happens if you manually set the extent in raster calculator to a much larger area?

Comment: Manually setting the extent in raster calculator just gave me a line, so I gave up! I was able to do it in ArcGIS